# Is there a permutation solution to the 'probability of seeing all die faces in $n$ rolls' problem?

Tags: probability, permutations, dice

Here's the question (from Conroy's dice problems):

*We roll a six-sides die n times. What is the probability that all faces have appeared?*

I understand the inclusion-exclusion answer to this question, but I don't understand why my alternate solution doesn't work:

Faces 1-6 can be placed/permuted in ${}_nP_r$ ways with $n=n, r=6$ among the n die rolls. There are $6^{n-6}$ permutations for the remaining die rolls, giving ${}_nP_6 * 6^{n-6}$ different permutations with all faces 1-6 out of a possible $6^n$ permutations. So I get an answer of $\dfrac{{}_nP_6}{6^{6}}$, but apparently this is wrong. What am I missing?

Comment: In this way, you don't take into account the fact that the subset $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ can be found in many different subsets of set of results...

Comment: @JeanMarie Could you elaborate?

Comment: Another point : it is not permutations that you should consider : the fact that you have 132564 instead of 346251 isn't relevant for this problem ; you cannot express in this way the fact that all numbers have appeared at least one...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are over-counting. If a sequence has multiple ways to select six places in the sequence containing the numbers $1,2,\dots,6$, then that sequence is counted multiple times by the formula ${}_{n}P_{6}\cdot 6^{n-6}$.

For example, with $n=8$, consider the sequence
$$
1,1,2,2,3,4,5,6.
$$
This is counted exactly four times by your method, because there are four ways to select six entries which are numbered $1,2,\dots,6$.

- $\color{blue}1,1,\color{blue}2,2,\color{blue}3,\color{blue}4,\color{blue}5,\color{blue}6$
- $\color{blue}1,1,2,\color{blue}2,\color{blue}3,\color{blue}4,\color{blue}5,\color{blue}6$
- $1,\color{blue}1,\color{blue}2,2,\color{blue}3,\color{blue}4,\color{blue}5,\color{blue}6$
- $1,\color{blue}1,2,\color{blue}2,\color{blue}3,\color{blue}4,\color{blue}5,\color{blue}6$

This shows that ${}_nP_6 \cdot 6^{n-6}$ does not count the sequences you want uniquely, which explains why you are getting the wrong answer.